# execute a php file on another server

Tags: php, function, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, glusterfs

I'm using Amazon EC2 to host a website, with the aim of having the smallest instance possible to save on costs etc.

Part of my website has a php function that unzips an archive full of mp3's, then rezips them and moves it all to Amazon S3 storage.

That particular function is very resource hungry on the micro EC2 instance that we're running.
So, we've setup another server (running Gluster) just for storing temp files and processing these temp files.

The problem i have now is how do i move over the previously mentioned function to the 'processing' server and trigger it to run from the 'main' server?

I want to have something like the below:

Publish post on main server -> Send command to processing server to execute unzip etc -> process -> return any required information from processing server back to main server

Hopefully that all makes sense.
Unfortunately, my PHP knowledge is basic, and my server knowledge is even less... but i'm willing to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create another site on the other server that doesn't have any pages but is just accessed through web service requests, like REST.

Check out a framework like Symfony2 to set this up easily.

Have your main server page call a web service and pass through the information (zip, etc) it needs and you web service can execute the process on the process server.